# flutter Card component doesn't turn to white color

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have a flutter app, I am running it on Android studio HedgeHog patch 1. And the latest flutter as well. I can run my android app fine with no errors, however I have a card component

[image]

That doesn't turn white, instead, it has that light green color.
On the card component, if I set the color: Colors.blue, it does change the color.

[image]

But I need the background to be white. And setting color: Colors.white keeps giving me that green color in the first image.

I've checked all the places that I might have a green color but haven't found anything with the same color. I'm a new developer on the project and actually I don't have much experience in flutter, and no one is also in the team that knows where is this color coming from.

Any guidance on how I can find this color and be able to change it is much appreciated.

Also happy to answer any questions

Code for the card section

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.select_a_product),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data!.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              vm.addProductToList(data![index]);
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      ConfiguratorDetailedView(data: data![index], vm: vm),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 12.0,
                          top: 12.0,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  data![index].description!,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            FormSpacer(
                              height: 15.0,
                            ),
                            Center(
                              child: Image.memory(
                                const Base64Decoder()
                                    .convert(data![index].image),
                                scale: 5,
                              ),
                            ),
                            FormSpacer(
                              height: 15.0,
                            ),
                            // A bunch of Text component
                            dataColumnSpacer,
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color:
                              kTabBarBackgroundColor, // Replace with your desired color
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Select',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )));
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: can you share the complete `build` method?

Comment: updated @MendelG. I updated the code section to have everything

Comment: are you using material 3?

Comment: Also, are you using custom theme's? try setting: `surfaceTintColor: Colors.white`  on the `Card`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And setting color: Colors.white keeps giving me that green color in the first image.

I'd assume that you're using material3 with a custom theme.

What you can do is to set the [`surfaceTintColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card/surfaceTintColor.html) to `Colors.white`

```dart
Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    surfaceTintColor: Colors.white, // <-- Set this to white
)
```